# UITableView inside UIScrollView with date

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I want to show a UITableView inside UIScrollView.  In UITableView header I want to show the current date at first and then if the user scrolls left it should show the previous date and if the user scrolls right is should show the next date... And I want to disable the vertical scrolling...

Here's my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
self.title = @"2017-02-01";

_scrollView.delegate = self;
_scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.scrollView.frame) * 3, CGRectGetHeight(self.scrollView.frame));
_scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
_scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
_scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
}
```

With this I can scroll right for 1 time and then its not scrolling. I tried some solutions but its not working...

Comment: You shouldn't put a table view in a scroll view. Table view is already a scroll view.

Comment: tableview is the subclass of scrollview, you can directly access the scroll delegates in tableview

Comment: I want it to scroll like a page when the user swipes... How can we achieve it without scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipageviewcontroller), which does exactly as you need.

Every time the user swipes left or right, the page view controller asks for the previous or next view controller - which will be an new instance of your view controller containing a UITableView (set up for the required date).

And to disable scrolling on the table, use `tableView.scrollEnabled = NO`. (Table views can only scroll vertically, so this will disable vertical scrolling).

Answer (score 0):

In the Attributes Inspector, you can uncheck the tick at **Scrolling Enabled** inorder to disable vertical scrolling.

[You can check on this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13HWp.png)